# How to replace empty spaces with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in sql server 2012 which contain white spaces. I want to replace these empty spaces with NULL. I have written the following query but its not working.

```
SELECT replace(COLUMN1, '',NULL) 
FROM Orders;
```

How to achieve the above functionality. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`nullif`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

```
select nullif(Column1, '') from Orders
```

Comment: Thanks dear, its giving the desired result. before mark as answer i want to ask that how nullif compare with empty space and convert into NULL, can you please clarify me little??? Really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: @user3004110 `NULLIF` will return `NULL` if the value is equal to the second argument.

Comment: What this answer misses is why it works if `Column1` contains `' '`: string comparisons in SQL Server ignore trailing whitespace, so `'a '` and `'a'` compare as equal, and similarly for `' '` and `''`.

Comment: Adding a note here that `NULLIF` matching on an empty string returns NULL even if the column value has any number of whitespace characters (e.g. `''`, `' '`, `'    '`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle the situation where the value consists of spaces or has zero length, then use `ltrim()` or `like`:

```
 select (case when value like '%[^ ]%' then value end)
```

Similarly,

```
select (case when ltrim(value) <> '' then value end)
```

Comment: There is no need for such complexity. My answer will handle this situation as well.

Comment: @podiluska . . . Relying on the fact that `''` is equal to `'    '` seems confusing to me.  I prefer to be explicit about such logic.

Answer (score 1):

The query below:

```
select REPLACE(ColumnName,'',NULL)as tb from TableName
```

can not be used as it returns all value of this column with NULL only. Because if any parameter of Replace function is null then it returns only NULL.

It can be advisable to use `NULLIF(columnName, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
declare @Blank nvarchar(1)=''

SELECT nullif(COLUMN1,@Blank) 
FROM Orders;
```

Its select all COLUMN1 records as null if thay are blank.