# IF item not present then print NONE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to Run a SQL query where I have few items and their types for example RENT ,LEASE or PURCHASE. The problem is some items may or may not have all three of them but any one or two of them. But I want to return NONE instead of Blank if a item doesn't have particular type.

My current query is :

```
select DISTINCT ITEM_ID,  UOM, LIST_PRICE from PRICELIST_TABLE
where item_id IN ('XYZ')
and PRICELIST_HDR in (select Pricelist_Hdr_Key from SMCFS93.YPM_PRICELIST_HDR where PRICELIST_NAME IN ('ALL') and SELLER_ORGANIZATION_CODE IN ('20'))
```

How do I make sure that even if the item of particular type is not present I get NONE. for e.g

```
ITEM_ID   UOM        PRICE     
ITEMX     PURCHASE   0
ITEMX     RENT       NONE  # none if not exist
```

Comment: Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710530/how-to-replace-empty-spaces-with-null[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710530/how-to-replace-empty-spaces-with-null)

Comment: @maryrio7 I am not saying the column is blank , I am saying that the RENT(e.g here) doesn't exist.

Comment: @Duck_dragon . . . What happened to `LEASE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows, then a `left join` to bring in the values you want:

```
with pl as (
      select DISTINCT ITEM_ID, UOM, LIST_PRICE
      from PRICELIST_TABLE
      where item_id IN ('XYZ') and
            PRICELIST_HDR in (select Pricelist_Hdr_Key
                              from SMCFS93.YPM_PRICELIST_HDR
                              where PRICELIST_NAME IN ('ALL') and
                                     SELLER_ORGANIZATION_CODE IN ('20')
                             )
      )
select i.item_id, u.uom, pl.list_price
from (select distinct item_id from pl) i cross join
     (select 'RENT' as uom from dual union all
      select 'LEASE' as uom from dual union all
      select 'PURCHASE' as uom from dual
     ) u left join
     pl
     on pl.item_id = i.item_id and pl.uom = u.uom;
```

The `cross join` creates all combinations of items and the uom categories you care about.  The `left join` then brings in the data that you want.

If you want the string `'NONE'` instead of `NULL`, then you need to consider types.  If `LIST_PRICE` is a string, no problem:

```
coalesce(list_price, 'NONE') as list_price
```

If not, you need to convert the value:

```
coalesce(to_char(list_price), 'NONE') as list_price
```

Comment: The thing is lets say if PURCHASE doesn't exist but I want to print list price of PURCHASE(UOM type) as NONE/ NULL

Comment: @Duck_dragon . . . I see.  The filtering in your query is filtering those out entirely from your subset.  No problem, just hard-code the values you want.

Comment: This works as expected. Can you please explain in short how does it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()`

```
select DISTINCT ITEM_ID,  UOM, coalesce(to_char(LIST_PRICE),'None')
from PRICELIST_TABLE left join SMCFS93.YPM_PRICELIST_HDR 
on PRICELIST_HDR =Pricelist_Hdr_Key and PRICELIST_NAME ='ALL' 
and SELLER_ORGANIZATION_CODE ='20'
where item_id ='XYZ'
```

Comment: Basically UOM is the item TYPE

Comment: @Duck_dragon, yes you need to do it for price column

Comment: okay. I tried running it . I am getting inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Comment: this isn't working, maybe that's because lets say for ITEMX only RENT exist as UOM and it doesn't have a entry for PURCHASE or LEASE. Do you think this is  the case

Comment: Not an answer.  If you wanted to print NULL instead of NONE, it would be easy.

Comment: @WalterMitty so basically you are saying I can't print something if it doesn't exist. I mean it makes sense . Can I write a SQL function to handle this.